# PHP cannot connect to mysql after moving DB & website to the same machine

Tags: php, mysql

I updated my server & moved both server itself & website on the same machine.
After doing that, my website won't connect to DB anymore. 
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on aws

I'll include connection script, because a friend said my code might be too old for php 7. Other then that I'm looking for any suggestions which might result in fixing my problem.

```
include "../config.php";
$link = @mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
if (!$link) 
{
    $error = "Cannot access MYSQL, please contact admin!<br />";
    $error .= mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error();
    die($error);
}
$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name);
if (!$db) 
{
$error = "Failed to select database.<br />";
$error .= mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error();
die($error);
}
$lang = @mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: There are any error message in logs?

Comment: No, before moving website & server to same machine everything worked fine. But I did use older php version in old machine.

Comment: `mysql_*`  is removed in php7. Removing `@` would have told you that!

Comment: So translate to `mysqli_*` functions or class. Or downgrade php to 5.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ is an error control operator. It means to php "if this call fails, let's log nothing and let's continue the trip"
So remove those @ symbols before your mysql calls then see your logs.

Anyway those mysql calls won't be accepted by php7.
You have now to use PDO or MySQLi

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Thank you, guess I got to change change it.